# FPC fails to compile CVTSD2SS instruction

Tags: delphi, freepascal

I have the following asm code that compiles in Delphi 10.3.3 but fails in FPC 3.2.0:

```
procedure LoadSingle(P: Pointer); assembler;
asm
    MOV RAX, P
    CVTSD2SS XMM0, QWORD PTR [RAX]
end;
```

with the following error:

```
Error: Asm: [cvtsd2ss reg??,mem128] invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

Kindly help me to convert the above into a working FPC code. Switch {$MODE DELPHI} is present.

Comment: Not sure why this fails, it looks valid to me, but this code looks dubious even in Delphi. The `assembler` serves no purpose. And it seems pointless to move the address from rcx to rax. It also seems odd that you would use asm for this. Why not just assign to a single variable? It's also hard to see what the real motivation is because you do nothing with the register once you've loaded it.

Comment: Try adding {$asmmode intel}  after the {$mode}.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Still not working.

Comment: I tried with 3.3.1 and for me it worked. I now also tested 3.2.2 and it failed

Answer (score 0):

It works with FPC 3.3.1. Thanks Marco.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).